# Two Hibernate Application Connected with Same Database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

We have two java-spring-hibernate application. Both are connected with same MySql Database. These applications are hosted in two different data centers.

What kind of impact it may create on ACIDity of database.

Thank you!

Comment: I maybe wrong with this but here's my thoughts. Multiple or single application in one single database have no differences. The problem will always lies on same record accessed by different user(or different application) at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACIDity is not affected. whether two connections come from the same application or from different ones doesn't matter as far as the database is concerned.
You might worry about performance issues though.